# How to avoid solid polygon covered by line plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

If I want a solid polygon with line plot covered by it, how to do it.

```
set object 1 poly from 1,1 to 1,4 to 5,1 to 1,1 fs solid border 1

plot [0:6] [0:6] x*x
```

The result looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `front` keyword to move the polygon to the front layer so that it covers the line:

```
set object 1 poly from 1,1 to 1,4 to 5,1 to 1,1 fs solid border 1 front
plot [0:6] [0:6] x*x
```

[image: polygon in front of a line]